# Passing (yield) fixtures as test parameters (with a temp directory)

Tags: python, pytest

### Question

Is it possible to pass yielding pytest fixtures (for setup and teardown) as parameters to test functions?

### Context

I'm testing an object that reads and writes data from/to files in a single directory. That path of that directory is saved as an attribute of the object.

I'm having trouble with the following:

1. using a temporary directory with my test; and
2. ensuring that the directory is removed after each test.

### Example

Consider the following (test_yieldfixtures.py):

```
import pytest, tempfile, os, shutil
from contextlib import contextmanager
    
@contextmanager
def data():
    datadir = tempfile.mkdtemp()  # setup
    yield datadir
    shutil.rmtree(datadir)        # teardown
    
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, datadir, errorfile):
        self.datadir = datadir
        self.errorfile = errorfile

    
@pytest.fixture
def thing1():
    with data() as datadir:
        errorfile = os.path.join(datadir, 'testlog1.log')
        yield Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)

@pytest.fixture
def thing2():
    with data() as datadir:
        errorfile = os.path.join(datadir, 'testlog2.log')
        yield Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('thing', [thing1, thing2])
def test_attr(thing):
    print(thing.datadir)
    assert os.path.exists(thing.datadir)
```

Running `pytest test_yieldfixtures.py` outputs the following:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_attr[thing0] ______________________________

thing = <generator object thing1 at 0x0000017B50C61BF8>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('thing', [thing1, thing2])
    def test_attr(thing):
>        print(thing.datadir)
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'props'

test_mod.py:39: AttributeError
```

OK. So fixture functions don't have a the properties of my class. Fair enough.

### Attempt 1

A function won't have the properties, so I tried calling that functions to actually get the objects. However, that just

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('thing', [thing1(), thing2()])
def test_attr(thing):
    print(thing.props['datadir'])
    assert os.path.exists(thing.get('datadir'))
```

Results in:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_attr[thing0] ______________________________

thing = <generator object thing1 at 0x0000017B50C61BF8>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('thing', [thing1(), thing2()])
    def test_attr(thing):
>       print(thing.datadir)
E       AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'props'

test_mod.py:39: AttributeError
```

### Attempt 2

I also tried using `return` instead of `yield` in the `thing1/2` fixtures, but that kicks me out of the `data` context manager and removes the directory:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_attr[thing0] ______________________________

thing = <test_mod.Thing object at 0x000001C528F05358>

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('thing', [thing1(), thing2()])
    def test_attr(thing):
        print(thing.datadir)
>       assert os.path.exists(thing.datadir)
```

### Closing

To restate the question: Is there anyway to pass these fixtures as parameters and maintain the cleanup of the temporary directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your `data` function / generator into a fixture. Then use [`request.getfixturevalue()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue) to dynamically run the named fixture.

```
import pytest, tempfile, os, shutil
from contextlib import contextmanager

@pytest.fixture # This works with pytest>3.0, on pytest<3.0 use yield_fixture
def datadir():
    datadir = tempfile.mkdtemp()  # setup
    yield datadir
    shutil.rmtree(datadir)        # teardown

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, datadir, errorfile):
        self.datadir = datadir
        self.errorfile = errorfile


@pytest.fixture
def thing1(datadir):
    errorfile = os.path.join(datadir, 'testlog1.log')
    yield Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)

@pytest.fixture
def thing2(datadir):
    errorfile = os.path.join(datadir, 'testlog2.log')
    yield Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('thing_fixture_name', ['thing1', 'thing2'])
def test_attr(request, thing):
    thing = request.getfixturevalue(thing) # This works with pytest>3.0, on pytest<3.0 use getfuncargvalue
    print(thing.datadir)
    assert os.path.exists(thing.datadir)
```

Going one step futher, you can parametrize the `thing` fixtures like so:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, datadir, errorfile):
        self.datadir = datadir
        self.errorfile = errorfile

@pytest.fixture(params=['test1.log', 'test2.log'])
def thing(request):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as datadir:
        errorfile = os.path.join(datadir, request.param)
        yield Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)

def test_thing_datadir(thing):
    assert os.path.exists(thing.datadir)
```

Comment: This nudged me in the right direction and I ended up with something much, much, shorter, going a bit beyond the original scope of the question. Do you mind if I append it to the bottom of your answer?

Comment: This second solution is quite elegant. However, it's still a bit non-standard for pytest. There are built in fixtures in pytest, one of which is tmpdir, that does exactly what you want. I recommend at least reading up on tmpdir and tmpdir_factory.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary directories and files are handled by pytest using the built in fixtures **tmpdir** and **tmpdir_factory**.

For this usage, **tmpdir** should be sufficient: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html

Also, **paramertrized fixtures** would work well for this example.
These are documented here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize

```
import os
import pytest


class Thing:
    def __init__(self, datadir, errorfile):
        self.datadir = datadir
        self.errorfile = errorfile


@pytest.fixture(params=(1, 2))
def thing(request, tmpdir):
    errorfile_name = 'testlog{}.log'.format(request.param)
    errorfile = tmpdir.join(errorfile_name)
    return Thing(datadir=str(tmpdir), errorfile=str(errorfile))


def test_attr(request, thing):
    assert os.path.exists(thing.datadir)
```

BTW, In [Python Testing with pytest](https://pragprog.com/book/bopytest/python-testing-with-pytest), parametrized fixtures are covered in ch3. tmpdir and other built in fixtures are covered in ch4.

Comment: is `tmpdir` added to the local namespace when `pytest` is imported?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Use `pytest --fixtures` to see which fixtures are available either through built in pytest fixtures or fixtures added by plugins or your own code.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem but I'm not sure about the solution.  The problem:

Your functions thing1 and thing2 contain yield statements.  When you call a function like that, the returned value is a "generator object."  It's an **iterator** - a sequence of values, which is of course not the same thing as the first value of `yield`, or any one particular value.

Those are the objects being passed to your `test_attr` function.  The test environment is doing that for you automagically, or at least I think that's how it works.

What you really want is the object created in your `yield` expression, in other words, `Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)`.  There are three ways to get a generator to emit its individual values: by calling `next(iter)`, by calling `iter.__next__()` or by using the iterator in a loop with an `in` expression.

One possibility is to iterate the generator once.  Like this:

```
def test_attr(thing):
    first_thing = next(thing)
    print(first_thing.datadir)
    assert os.path.exists(first_thing.datadir)
```

`first_thing` will be the object you want to test, i.e., `Thing(datadir=datadir, errorfile=errorfile)`.

But this is only the first hurdle.  The generator function is not finished.  Its internal "program counter" is just after the `yield` statement.  So you haven't exited the context manager and haven't deleted your temporary directory yet.  To do this you must call `next(thing)` again and catch a `StopIteration` exception.

Alternatively I think this will work:

```
def test_attr(thing):
    for a_thing in thing:
        print(a_thing.datadir)
        assert os.path.exists(a_thing.datadir)
```

The `in` expression loops through all the items in the iterator (there's only one) and exits gracefully when StopIteration occurs.  The function exits from the context manager and your work is done.

To me it's an open question whether this makes your code more or less readable and maintainable.  It's a bit clumsy.

Comment: The **yield** in pytest fixtures separates the setup (before the yield) and the teardown (after the yield). It is different than a traditional generator.