# Parametrized test fixtures in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test suite where I create instance of object and replace kafka consumer in that object with my mock consumer, such as:

```
def mock_consumer(fixtures):
    with open(fixtures) as fixturefile:
        messages = fixturefile.readlines()
    for msg in messages:
        encoded = mock.MagicMock()
        encoded.value.decode = lambda x: msg
        yield encoded
```

then I use that mock_consumer to create an instance of my object:

```
@pytest.fixture
@patch('service.producer.kafka_init')
def msg_producer_test1(mock_kafka_init):
    pr = producer(config)
    pr.balanced_consumer = mock_consumer('tests/test1.json')
    return pr
```

and then I write test:

```
def test_that_we_process_message_correctly(msg_producer_test1):
    msg_producer_test1.process()
    assert (result = what_we_expect)
```

But I want to abstract it out so I will do something like:

```
def test_we_process_message_correctly(mock_msg_producer, 'tests/test1.json')
    mock_msg_producer.process()
```

What would be best way to do that?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225950/passing-yield-fixtures-as-test-parameters-with-a-temp-directory

Comment: So you want to parametrize a fixture in test? Instead of doing `@pytest.fixture(params=('tests/test1.json',))`, you want to set the params in the test signature?